# How to create split 3 columns in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query like:

```
$menus = Categories::all();
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the output is this (by id):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

My website has a 5-column layout. I need to split/divide these results into 5 columns such that it ends up like this:

**I want to this order**

```
 1 |  4 |  7 | 10 |  13
 2 |  5 |  8 | 11 |  14
 3 |  6 | 9  | 12 |  15
```

The 5 column layout is split like this (the total number of columns is 25):

AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $menus = Category::all();
    view()->share(['menus' => $menus]);
}
```

blade

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
    <div class="tab-pane fade {{ $loop->first ? 'show active' : '' }}" id="v-pills-{{ $menu->id }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-{{ $menu->id }}-tab">
        @for($rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < $menus->first()->count(); $rowIndex++)
            <div class="row w-100 position-absolute">
                @for($columnIndex = 0; $columnIndex <= 5; $columnIndex++)
                    @if ($menus->get($rowIndex)->has($columnIndex))
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach($menu->getChild as $child)
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ $child->path() }}" class="">
                                            {{ $menus->get($rowIndex)->get($columnIndex)->id }}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach($child->getChild as $subChild)
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="{{ $subChild->path() }}" class="">
                                                    {{ $subChild->name }}
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                @endfor
            </div>
        @endfor
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I get an error

[image: error]

How can I split $results up like this? Any way to make use of Laravel's Collection methods?

Comment: Can't you just display all columns one by one in html and make columns with css, ex. `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);`?

Comment: No, I want to use with laravel code

Comment: @AdrianKokot, I see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZzIs.png

Comment: As you should have noticed, making this in php is a mess, what you should do is print all the categories in the same `<ul>` and make the vertical ordering using css (grid/flex). it will give you the same result and keep the code clean for further maintenance/update/debug.

Comment: "No, I want to use with laravel code " Why? If something can simply be done with css, why would you write "complex" PHP/Laravel code? Reorganizing the array and multiple loops will only take more time to process.

Answer (score 1):

I would use bootstrap or grid layout so you don't need any moving of the data order:

```css
div[class^="col"] {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        3
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        4
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        5
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        6
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        7
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        8
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        9
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        10
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        11
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        12
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        13
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        14
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        15
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```